# PowerShell - Select tags between regular expressions on Parsing html files

Tags: powershell

A simple example. I have this lines on 2 different html files, on Folder1 and Folder2. I want to parse (copy) some line from one folder to another, with REGEX, from the tag `<tr>` to `</tr>` tag.

The problem is that are a lots of `<tr>` and `<tr>` in the file, so I framed between the comments (`<!--START-->` and `<!--FINNISH-->`) the exact `<tr>` tags that I want to parse.

```
<html>
<body>
<table>

<!--START-->
<tr>
new contents
</tr>
<!--FINNISH-->

other lines 

<tr>
I love powershell because is hard to understand <tags/>
</tr>

other code

<tr>
keep stuff including <embedded/> <tags/>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

THE PROBLEM: How can I modify this PoweShell Code, as to select (with regex) only those `<tr>`and `</tr>` tags that are framed between the comments (`<!--START-->` and `<!--FINNISH-->`)

```
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem 'c:\Folder1'
$destinationFolder = 'c:\Folder2'

foreach ($file in $sourceFiles) {

$sourceContent = Get-Content $file.FullName -Raw
$contentToInsert = [regex]::match($sourceContent,"(?ms)<tr>(.+)</tr>").value
$destinationContent = Get-Content $destinationFolder\$($file.Name) -Raw
$destinationContent = $destinationContent -replace '(?ms)<tr>(.+)</tr>',$contentToInsert

Set-Content -Path $destinationFolder\$($file.Name) -Value $destinationContent -Encoding UTF8

} #end foreach file
```

The result should be only `new contents`. So, I need to parse only the content of the `<tr></tr>` tags between `<!--START-->` and `<!--FINNISH-->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THE SOLUTION. It was all about a matter of REGEX, I had select all `<!--START-->` `<!--FINNISH-->` tags that also contains `<tr>` `</tr>` tags, so as to parse only their content

```
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem 'c:\Folder1'  
$destinationFolder = 'c:\Folder2'

foreach ($file in $sourceFiles) {

$sourceContent = Get-Content $file.FullName -Raw
$contentToInsert = [regex]::match($sourceContent,"<!--START-->(\s*)<tr>[\s\S]+</tr>(\s*)<!--FINNISH-->").value
$destinationContent = Get-Content $destinationFolder\$($file.Name) -Raw
$destinationContent = $destinationContent -replace '<!--START-->(\s*)<tr>[\s\S]+</tr>(\s*)<!--FINNISH-->',$contentToInsert

Set-Content -Path $destinationFolder\$($file.Name) -Value $destinationContent -Encoding UTF8

} #end foreach file
```

Answer (score 0):

For structured text strings (including [serialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) objects), I recommend you to use the related (.Net) parser rather than peeking and poking directly in the string using regular expressions with string methods along with e.g. `[regex]::match`.

For example:

**Input**

```
$Html = '<html>
<body>
<table>

<!--START-->
<tr>
new contents
</tr>
<!--FINNISH-->

other lines 

<tr>
I love powershell because it a has an easy syntax<tags/>
</tr>

Even when invoking .Net methods

<tr>
keep stuff including <embedded/> <tags/>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>'
```

**Code**

```
$Unicode = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Html)
$Document = New-Object -Com 'HTMLFile'
if ($Document.IHTMLDocument2_Write) { $Document.IHTMLDocument2_Write($Unicode) } else { $Document.write($Unicode) }
$InMarker = $False
foreach($Table in $Document.body.getElementsByTagName('table')) {
     Switch ($Table.All) {
         { $_.Text -eq '<!--START-->' } { $InMarker = $True }
         { $_.tagName -eq 'TR' -and $InMarker } { $_.innerHtml }
         { $_.Text -eq '<!--FINNISH-->' } { $InMarker = $False }
     }
}
```

**Result**

```
new contents
```

Comment: hello. please put the entire code + my code in your answer, to be complete for testing

Comment: by the way, the result should be only `new contents`. I need to parse only the content of the `<tr></tr>` tags between `<!--START-->` and `<!--FINNISH-->`

Comment: yes, iRon, thanks. But, for everyone to understand better, please Update Your Answer also with any of my code. I will Vote you, but everyone must have the all code.

Comment: I run just your code, see this print screen https://snipboard.io/rhJ8XD.jpg  This is why I need you to put the entire code + mine, so everyone to see  at once how it works :)

Comment: let me put it another way. I run your code, and it is not working. I really don't know how did you manage to get that nice Result. So, you should make a code, which everyone can copy and work perfectly. :)

In my example, is simple. There are 2 identical files, in 2 folders, except the information from tags `<!--START-->` and `<!--FINNISH-->` That information must be parse / copy from one file to another

Comment: I copy all your INPUT code, put it in a html file. Run it with your code. By the way, can you add a **path** to your code? Maybe this will help me to understand.

Comment: yes, now I understand. Works good. But my request was a little bit different. I write in my question `I have this lines on 2 different html files, on Folder1 and Folder2. I want to parse (copy) some line from one folder to another`. Your code does not parsing a code from a file to another, from a specific folder to another :)